# External react library updating store in parent UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hey I have a task that I don't really know how to get on with.

Basically I have a react library that is installed in a bunch of UI applications, so each UI application has this library in its `package.json`.

Now, I have this one component (which is a [MUI Drawer](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/)) that displays my theme as a switch with some text - either dark or light. This happens completely on the UI level and is not saved when the page is refreshed.

[image]

The task then should be simple - when this theming component is mounted it should fetch by calling `useEffect` all the user's settings and use a callback that was passed down to set the settings in the parent UI's store. Right? The issue is, that this component only mounts if I open the drawer.

Changing this to a JS class would work since `constructor()` is called when the page is refreshed. But this way is not encouraged.

[image]

The last idea I had is to add user settings fetching functionality to a top component that wraps the entire application but that would complicate an already complex component.

Any other ideas?

This is what my component looks like:

```
const UserSettings = ({switchTheme, title}) => {
    /**
     * Fetch theme and other user settings
     */
    const fetchUserSettings = () => {
        
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUserSettings();
    }, []);

    /**
     * Should be called via dispatch to set the theme in parent UI's store
     */
    const toggleTheme = () => {
        switchTheme();
    };

    const switchToTheme = useSelector((state) => state.themeColor.switchTo);
    return (
        <StyledDiv>
            <h5>{title}</h5>
            <Button onClick={UserService.doLogout} variant='contained'>Logout</Button>

            <StyledDivider />

            <StyledH5>
                {switchToTheme}
                {' '}
Mode
            </StyledH5>
            <MaterialUISwitch defaultChecked onChange={toggleTheme} />
        </StyledDiv>
    );
};

UserSettings.propTypes = {
    switchTheme: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default UserSettings;
```